# How to display variable key values of json in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, html

I have following JSON:

```
[
   {
      "item0":"red",
      "item1":"green"},
   {
      "item0":"blue",
      "item1":"black",
      "item2":"purple"
   }
   {
      "item0":"yellow"
   }
]
```

Now I want these values to populate in my HTML by `ng-repeat`. But since my Key value is changing in JSON everytime, I am unable to use the code. Following is the structure of my HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="upsell in upsellData">       
  <div class="style-select prefilled">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="{{upsell.item0}}">
     </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="{{upsell.item1}}">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This just diplays 0th element, 1st element, 2nd element etc.. but my key values can vary according to data.

Can someone please help me in getting the values for variable number of keys through `ng-repeat`?

I also tried with `$index` and nested `ng-repeat`, but didn't got desired result.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="upsell in upsellData">       
  <div class="style-select prefilled">
    <div class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="(key, value) in upsell">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="{{ value }}">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, I would consider rearranging your data before iterating over it.

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day :) Can you tell me how do you want to rearrange the data?

Comment: @RituG.Vijaywargiya You could iterate over the data, parse keys and rearrange it according to your needs. The point is that you do that in your business logic rather than in your views. I proposed that because I was not quite sure if iterating over key / value pairs is sufficient in your use case.

Answer (score 0):

use nested ng-repeats, using (key,value) in the inner ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="upsell in upsellData">       
  <div class="style-select prefilled">
    <div class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="(key,value) in upsell">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="{{value}}">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested-repeat [ng-repeat within ng-repeat] as (key, val) pair :

```
<div ng-repeat="upsell in upsellData">       
  <div class="style-select prefilled">
    <div class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="(key, val) in upsell">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="{{val}}">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```